# Как узнать остальные элементы строки таблицы HTML при её редактировании

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код редактирования html таблицы:

```
var editable = {
    // (B) PROPERTIES
    selected : null, // current selected cell
    value : "", // current selected cell value

    // (C) "CONVERT" TO EDITABLE CELL
    edit : cell => {
        // (C1) REMOVE "DOUBLE CLICK TO EDIT"
        cell.ondblclick = "";

        // (C2) EDITABLE CONTENT
        cell.contentEditable = true;
        cell.focus();

        // (C3) "MARK" CURRENT SELECTED CELL
        cell.classList.add("edit");
        editable.selected = cell;
        editable.value = cell.innerHTML;

        // (C4) PRESS ENTER/ESC OR CLICK OUTSIDE TO END EDIT
        window.addEventListener("click", editable.close);
        cell.onkeydown = evt => {
            if (evt.key=="Enter" || evt.key=="Escape") {
                editable.close(evt.key=="Enter" ? true : false);
                return false;
            }
        };
    },
    // (D) END "EDIT MODE"
    close : evt => { if (evt.target != editable.selected) {
        // (D1) CANCEL - RESTORE PREVIOUS VALUE
        if (evt === false) {
            editable.selected.innerHTML = editable.value;
        }

        // (D2) REMOVE "EDITABLE"
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        editable.selected.contentEditable = false;

        // (D3) RESTORE CLICK LISTENERS
        window.removeEventListener("click", editable.close);
        let cell = editable.selected;
        cell.ondblclick = () => editable.edit(cell);

        // (D4) "UNMARK" CURRENT SELECTED CELL
        editable.selected.classList.remove("edit");
        editable.selected = null;
        editable.value = "";

        // (D5) DO WHATEVER YOU NEED
        if (evt !== false) {
        console.log(cell.innerHTML);
        //
        }
    }}
};
```

Сама строка в таблице выглядит так:
[image: table]

Как можно узнать какой номер элемента строки я сейчас редактировал и первый элемент строки?

Comment: "а сейчас редактировал" - это "сейчас" это когда? После "close"? Первое, что приходит на ум, добавьте к B (Properties) дополнительное свойство, напр. "lastEditedCell" и в "close" сохраняйте ячейку, а по ней уже можно получить корневой элемент TR.

Comment: @XelaNimed можно пожалуйста поподробнее как получить корневой элемент tr?

Comment: [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)